# Automatic Redefining a global variable in the class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, variables

I want something like that:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> c = SomeClass(x)
>>> c.x
0
>>> x = 1
>>> c.x
1
```

Or

```
>>> x = 0
>>> c = SomeClass(x)
>>> c.x
0
>>> x = 1
>>> c.x
0
>>> c.update()
>>> c.x
1
```

I guess it's not a convencional way to do it and I know you could just make `def update(self,x): self.x = x` or `c.x = x` but that's not the way I want it, I just want to know if there is a way to achieve that.

Comment: What's wrong with `c.x = 1`?

Comment: @ TigerhawkT3, Nothing, as i wrote up there i just want know if there is a way to get that.

Comment: If you have no reason to avoid proper syntax and style, don't. You'll just make a big mess that accomplishes no useful purpose, and no one will understand your code (including yourself, a few weeks from now).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sure, just a silly question, i flagged it, ty for the answer\critic btw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a property:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return x
```

Comment: There's no `x` local to that function, so that will produce a `NameError`. It also doesn't have anything to do with the conversion of global variables to class or instance variables.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That depends on where `x` is defined. If it defined in the file as the class it will work. It not, the `return` line has to be modified. If someone uses global variables, the chance is very high that everything is in one file.

Comment: I see. However, it still just points to the global variable, which doesn't require anything more than `x=1` and a reference to `x`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, I told him how to do it, you told him that it might not be clever. So he got all the information to make a decision.

Answer (score -1):

override the **getattribute**  and **setattr**(self, attr, value) function in SomeClass, to get and set the x value in it.